# AVAudioPlayer stop all sounds playing on different view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer

I've an app with 3 view controllers. The first one generate a 5min track and when it goes to second view it keeps on playing in `setVolume:2.0` and same goes for 3rd view controller.
But on third `ViewCOntroller` there is a `UIButton` that re generate the first `ViewController`. And when it goes back to first view controller it starts that sound again and the previous one is already playing so it's a mix.
Now the sound was `init` on first `ViewController` so how can I stop it on third `ViewController`? It there any code that stops all the sounds playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the AVAudioPlayer as a global variable in your first ViewController. The effect will be that every instance of your first ViewController will be able to share the same player.

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

After that you can do something like this in ViewDidLoad:

```
if (!player) {
   AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
   [player play];
} else if (!player.playing) {
   [player play];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shared instance and be called from all viewController. So you can refer when to stop/play/load, etc.

```
@interface MainAVPlayer : AVAudioPlayer
+ (instancetype)shared;
@end

@implementation MainAVPlayer
+ (instancetype)shared {
  static id _sharedInstance = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
  dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
    _sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
  });
  return _sharedInstance;
}
@end
```

When accessing from other view controller call:

```
[[MainAVPlayer shared] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
[[MainAVPlayer shared] play];
```

p/s: there might be typo, writing from memory.